# Cocoapods inhibit_all_warnings! not working in 1.6.1 with Xcode 10.2.1 / Swift 5

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods

I updated to Xcode 10.2.1 (from 9.x), converted to Swift 5, and updated my cocoapods to their latest versions. Everything compiles and runs fine, but I'm getting Swift Compiler Warnings for a file in one of the installed pods (`FirebaseUI`). Does anyone know how I can suppress it? I already have `inhibit_all_warnings!` in my podfile, and until now it has successfully inhibited all warnings.

It is important to me to fix it because I run with zero warnings in my project, and treat warnings as errors in my release builds.

My environment is as follows:

- Xcode: 10.2.1.
- Cocoapods: 1.6.1.
- Warning:
  ****/MyProject/Pods/FirebaseUI/Auth/FirebaseAuthUI/FUIAuthUtils.h:20:17: Pointer is missing a nullability type specifier (_Nonnull, _Nullable,
  or _Null_unspecified)
- FirebaseUI: 6.2.1

Comment: I had to delete my Pods directory and do a fresh pod install for `inhibit_all_warnings!` to take effect.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @JamesBedford, but I tried that and it didn't work :-(